# My app is not compatible with any of the supported devices

Tags: android, sdk

I have published an android application made in Android Studio but at the Play Store it is showing that the is incompatible with my device and i have tried it on many different android smartphones with different android versions but it is showing the same message.
but I have declared the minimum SDk 15 and targeted SDK 23 but it is showing the same message even on the targeted SDK.

Screenshots are [First Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo5k6.png) and [Second Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNrE4.png)

and in the Play Store it tells 
Supported devices:
817
Unsupported devices:
15314

I have add this code in the manifest

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"

        />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="ldpi"
            android:screenSize="small" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="mdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    </compatible-screens>
```

Comment: *I have add this code in the manifest `<compatible-screens/>`* any reasons why? ... if your device is fx `mdpi` and  `large`  it will be not compatible

Comment: The app is already for normal and small  ldpi and mdpi

Comment: No, it is for (normal and mdpi) or (small and ldpi) or ... etc. And not for fx (mdpi and large)... For the start get rid of the supports-screens at all

Answer (score 0):

Will this code work

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>
```